# Loaded dae model looks pixelated with white lines n Three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, sketchup

I load a dae model created in Sketctup (https://graviditetsberegner.dk/square.skp) in Three.js. I found that dae models were the best regarding texture placement and hierarchical placement of the different components when going from Sketchup to Three.js. I load the model using the below code without any modification to meshes:

```
var modelLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

modelLoader.load("https://www.graviditetsberegner.dk/square.dae", function (dae)         {

    model = dae.scene.clone();
    scene.add(model);
    ...
```

The model loads fine, but when I rotate the camera (and sometimes just when it loads), it looks really blurry and white lines appear.

Is there an option or something I can set to make it looks smooth and without the white lines? I have tried antialias for the renderer without much effect.

A fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/35wc6myf/

It looks like this in SketchUp:
[image]

Comment: Enabling anti-aliasing and applying the device pixel ratio to the renderer makes the result more sharp, see https://jsfiddle.net/8eLk7b3y/1/. The wrong color of the lines looks like an issue in `ColladaLoader`. Does it work if you convert the model to `glTF`? It's actually the much better option for delivering 3D assets over the web and the recommended format of `three.js`.

Comment: It looks perfect in glTF, but I had issues with the position of textures when I attempted to use a canvas texture for displaying text. Using the dae format, the texture aligns as I would expect, but using glTF, the text texture is off and it's mirrored. But if glTF is recommended, I will continue working with this and maybe create a new post here describing the issues I face with glTF.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's better to fix your `glTF` based workflow than using `Collada`.

Comment: I have described the issues I experienced with glTF here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443872/assigned-texture-to-glb-model-in-three-js-is-reversed-and-only-working-with-thre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the export settings on your Sketchup file, but it looks like it's adding quite a few `LineSegments` objects with their color set to white. Could be that these exist in your scene hierarchy, but their visibility has been turned off, or they get added upon export. I was able to remove the white lines in your fiddle by adding this code right after you clone your scene:

```
model = dae.scene.clone();

model.children[0].children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.type == "LineSegments") {
        child.visible = false;
    }
});
```

Result:

[image: Model without white lines]

Comment: `ColladaLoader` actually applies a wrong material to the line segments (thus the color of them are white and not black). So it is an issue in the loader...