# Assigned texture to glb model in Three.js is reversed and only working with THREE.RepeatWrapping

Tags: three.js, 3d, sketchup

I load a glb model in Three.js generated in SketchUp. The file can be found here https://www.graviditetsberegner.dk/bpnew.skp

The model contains a group called text with a mesh. I want to display a texture containing text here. I use the below code:

```
var modelLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

modelLoader.load("https://www.graviditetsberegner.dk/bpnew.glb", function (gltf) {

model = gltf.scene.clone();
model.scale.set(50,50,50)
scene.add(model);

//Use canvas to draw texture and add it to the model group Text
var textModelMesh = FindMeshWithNameInModel(model, "Text");
var textTexture = CreateCanvasTexture("This is a test");

textTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
textTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

textModelMesh.material.map = textTexture;
```

I have two issues with the code:

- The text is mirrored. In other formats such as dae, the text is not mirrored
- The text is only displayed when I set wrapS and wrapT to RepeatWrapping. However, the texture used in SketchUp should be similar to the dimensions of the generated texture in the canvas.

How can I fix these issues?

A fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgmds9ce/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The text is mirrored. In other formats such as dae, the text is not mirrored

As mentioned in the official [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader) for `THREE.GLTFLoader` you have to set `Texture.flipY` to `false` if you manually replace a texture.

> The text is only displayed when I set wrapS and wrapT to RepeatWrapping. However, the texture used in SketchUp should be similar to the dimensions of the generated texture in the canvas.

The texture from the asset has also set `Texture.wrapS` and `Texture.wrapT` to `THREE.RepeatWrapping`.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d12t6p5q/1/

`three.js R105`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your quick reply! Apparently I didn't read the documentation for the gltf loader thoroughly enough.